# using annotationConfigApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(Item.class) to get all ollect all Spring configured Item beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi i have a class called

```
public class Item {
String name;
String value;
```

}

trying to get all the configured items from my yml file into a map like this

```
    @Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationConfigApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    Map<String , Item> items = annotationConfigApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(Item.class);
    System.out.println("Hello world" + items);

}
```

I am new to sping and I don't know how my yml/JSON file look like

should it be something similar to this

```
item
  name:hello
  value:asdsad

item
  name:abc
  value:asa
```

should i have any additional configuration as well?

Comment: What are you using to create beans from the YAML file? There's nothing in Spring Boot that will do that for you without you writing some code.

Comment: I have a list of items (i would like to have on on a yml/json config file and map it to Item object) 

i can use objectMapper for json file but i want to put that config file  on ApplicationContext , i am using springboot with commanlineRunner